# GStreamer screenshot video stream

Tags: console, gstreamer, screencast

When I use this command:

```
gst-launch ximagesrc ! video/x-raw-rgb,framerate=5/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! theoraenc !        oggmux ! filesink location=desktop.ogg
```

[ximagesrc usage](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-ximagesrc.html)

It shows me only desktop screenshot and video length is 0:00 or sometimes it just shows pictures without mouse motion.

More information:
Ubuntu 10.04.3
this is a text

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
gst-launch ximagesrc use-damage=0 ! video/x-raw-rgb,framerate=15/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! x264enc ! matroskamux ! filesink location="test.mkv"
```

Perhaps just the use-damage=0 parameter to ximagesrc will help.